# MVC Post form data with Editor template containing dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created an editor template that has a dropdown in it, and I can't get the selected value to come through when posting the form that wraps the partial view.

```
@model DDTestViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.DDTestViewModelChild)
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
}
```

Editor Template:

```
@model DDTestViewModelChild

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Items, new SelectList(Model.Items, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedItemID))
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeOtherValue)
```

ViewModels:

```
public class DDTestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public DDTestViewModelChild DDTestViewModelChild { get; set; }
}

public class DDTestViewModelChild
{
    public int SelectedItemID { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult DDEditorTest()
{
    var vm = new DDTestViewModel();
    var cvm = new DDTestViewModelChild();
    var items = new List<Item>();
    items.Add(new Item { ID = 1, Name = "Item 1" });
    items.Add(new Item { ID = 2, Name = "Item 2" });
    items.Add(new Item { ID = 3, Name = "Item 3" });
    items.Add(new Item { ID = 4, Name = "Item 4" });
    cvm.Items = items;
    vm.DDTestViewModelChild = cvm;
    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult DDEditorTest(DDTestViewModel vm)
{
    var selectedID = vm.DDTestViewModelChild.SelectedItemID; //selectedID is 0 always
    var someOtherValue = vm.DDTestViewModelChild.SomeOtherValue; //this value comes through
    return RedirectToAction("DDEditorTest");
}
```

When I post back to `DDEditorTest` the `SelectedItemID` of the child view model is 0 no matter what I select, but "SomeOtherValue" comes through from the form.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the dropdown selected item being bound to `Model.SelectedItemID` instead of something like `x => x.SelectedItemID`, but I don't know how I could do that.

Comment: you can actually see why its not binding by examining the rendered markup in browser.. name attribute should be the name of the binding property from the Model.. eg: for a field Model.TestClass.Field1 your element in markup should have the name "TestClass.Field1" for the default model binding to work properly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have binded it to wrong property, you have to bind it to `SelectedItem`, as the dropdown will post selected value of the **option**.

For Example:

```
<select id="SelectedItemID" name="SelectedItemID">
<option value="1">Some Option</option>
</select>
```

if the above option is selected in dropdown, its value attribute value will post in the form to action.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItemID, 
                      new SelectList(Model.Items, 
                                     "ID", 
                                     "Name", 
                                     Model.SelectedItemID))
```

See the [**Html.DropDownListFor() helper overload documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703462%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is list of all available [**overloads**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: oh! so that's what that first lambda is for. I'm new to MVC, was a bit confused about that. dropdownlist is a bit weird since it has a bit of redundancy. Thanks!

Comment: yes the first property is on the one you want the selected value to be posted